# how to generate java class from xsd by using xmlbeans in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, xsd, apache-axis, xmlbeans

I am new to gradle. In my project, i have xsd files and i would like to generate java classes from that xsd (using xmlbeans only). How to do that in gradle.

I am using axis2 1.6.1, gradle, xmlbean 2.3.0` (JAXB is not an option in my current project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use the ["xmlbeansPlugin"](https://github.com/rartavia/gradle-plugins) for this. Can't say now, whether it's possible to change the xmlbean's version to the older one.

All you need is to apply the plugin to your build script:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/rartavia/gradle-plugins/master/xmlbeansPlugin/xmlbeans.gradle'
```

Then declare `xmlbeans` configuration and it's dependency

```
configurations {
    xmlbeans
}

dependencies {
    xmlbeans 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.5.0'
}
```

After that you have to specify the xsd files location

```
sourceSets {
    schemas {
            srcDir = 'src/main/schemas'
    }
}
```

And now you can call `compileXmlSchemas` task to generate classes

Comment: Thanks. I have marked your reply as answer. I ended up with a similar solution: ant.taskdef(name:'xmlbean', classname: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean', classpath: configurations.xmlbeans.asPath)   and then: task compileXmlSchemas { doLast{
    ant.xmlbean(schema: 'xsd/Development/ProductInfoRequest.xsd', srcgendir: "src/main/java", classgendir: 'build/generated', classpath: Configurations.xmlbeans.asPath) }}

Answer (score 4):

I had to modify Stanislav's answer a bit to get the plugin working. Namely setting the sourceSets in the following manner:

```
sourceSets {
    xmlbeans {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['dir/schema']
        }
    }
}
```

in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Stek. That helps

Comment: I am getting the error with sourceSets. No such property: srcDirs for class: org.gradle.api.internal.NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate. any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

```
java -classpath xbean.jar org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler 
     -src <OUTPUT_SOURCE_FOLDER> 
     -out <OUTPUT>.jar <SOURCE>.xsd 
     -compiler "javac.exe" 
     -javasource "1.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for an answer to this question with latest gradle build (6.x), here is how I was able to configure the project in eclipse (Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)) and generated Java (8) classes from XSD files automatically with gradle task.

**code snippet in build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
     }
   }
   dependencies {
     classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.liferay:gradle-plugins-xsd-builder:1.0.10'
  } 
}
dependencies {
  compile "org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:4.0.0"
  ... //other dependencies
}
.... // other code
apply plugin: "com.liferay.xsd.builder"
```

After adding the above code, refresh eclipse and then update the gradle task view in eclipse, you should see the task: ***buildXSD*** under **build** group. Add all your XSD files in **xsd** folder (keep this folder at root of the project folder) and double-click on buildXSD task to generate all Java types from XSD, pretty clean. If you have any future XSD to be added, just drop that in **xsd** folder and run again the same task. This task will generate a jar file which contains all the Java Types in **lib** folder of your project.

[image: buildXSD task in gradle project]

For curious minds - currently, what we do is following:

1. Run the jar task under build folder which actually generates a jar file of the project (this project uses the Java classes generated from the XSD for certain webservice calls)
2. Then copy the both jar files: generated jar file from 1st step + XSD based generated jar files to the deploy folder in local machine
3. Another gradle task is ran which calls remote machine to stop the server, deploys the jars to the desired location and then starts the server. This gradle task also uses another plugin: https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/ which also works very well.

All the above steps are automated with single gradle task (clean + jar + customCopyTask + deployToServer) which works perfectly to automate this.
Note: The jar task also generates XSD based jar file as well. So may be you might want to write a custom jar task.