# How to format a value by xsd type?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I want to create xml files, defining the datatype and format of some fields. Like:

```
<fields>
    <field name="myfield" type="xsd:decimal" format="####.##" />
</fields>
```

Question: are there any buildin functions (or frameworks like apache or spring) that can detect the xsd `type` attribute, create an object accordingly and then format it using the definition given in `format` attribute?

```
//read from xml:
String type = "xsd:decimal";
String format = "####.##"; //could as well be HH:mm for xsd:date

//actual value:
String myfield = "123.4567";
```

Now: how can I detect the configured field type (xsd:decimal, xsd:short, xsd:date, xsd:time, etc), and format the field accordingly given the formatter?

Comment: You could use [`JAXB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) to generate xml from xsd. One example is [`here`](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/jaxb-generate-xml-xsd.html).

Comment: No, my question was: what can I use to create the java type accordingly to the xsd type? Like `xsd:decimal -> BigDecimal`, `xsd:string -> String`, `xsd:date -> GregorianCalendar`.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [this](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/guide/conXMLBeansSupportBuiltInSchemaTypes.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304634/how-to-generate-java-class-from-xsd-by-using-xmlbeans-in-gradle)